# Java Regex to group compound names

Tags: java, regex

I'm creating a java application that request some names on console, then using a regex to extract just names without commas and only for correct names according this expression:

`(\\w{2,}(|\\s\\w{2,})+)`

I checked the above expression on a web regex simulator and seems to work fine for my requirements but when I try to match it on Java by using Pattern and Matcher Classes it does not work fine for names like: **Alvaro de la Torre**.

It keeps splitting the name in 4 groups (in this example). I need the compound names to be just in one String.

I would highly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey David, a piece of advice: people with regex knowledge might easily understand, but in general you should provide examples of your input, your actual output and the desired output.

Comment: I think the pipe in your regex is the culprit. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we live in a deterministic world, machines follows deterministic rules. In particular, in regular expressions, if the first field of a capturing group is satisfied, the parser will not check for the second, if it's not strictly necessary.

So, since the first field of your nested capturing group (`(|\\s\\w{2,})`) is the empty string, the regex is satisfied with it, without checking for the other field. This is the reason why it returns 4 distinct results instead of 1.

An alternative regex is:

```
(\\w{2,}(\\s\\w{2,}|)+)
```

That inverts the order of the 2 fields in the capturing group.

An equivalent regex is:

```
(\\w{2,}(\\s\\w{2,})*)
```

Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/apSXpi/1) vs [this other one](https://regex101.com/r/apSXpi/2) (regex is slightly different for highlight reasons).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to extract a string like **"de la Torre"** from **"Alvaro de la Torre"**.

With your regex, the capturing group 2 is repeated with `+`, and it contains **" de"** on the first iteration, **" la"** on the second iteration, and **" Torre"** on the third and last iteration. So, when you finally get group 2 from the `Matcher`, it contains only **" Torre"**.

So, instead of repeating a capturing group, you have to [capture a repeated group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html):

```
"(\\w{2,}(|(\\s\\w{2,})+))"
```

Note the additional group enclosing the inner group and the `+`.

Now, when you get group 2 from the `Matcher`, it contains all the repetitions of the inner group, that is, **" de la Torre"**:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w{2,}(|(\\s\\w{2,})+))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Alvaro de la Torre");
matcher.matches();
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

Prints `" de la Torre"`.

---

A better equivalent version of the above regex is:

```
"\\w{2,}((?:\\s\\w{2,})*)"
```

And then get group 1 rather than 2. It makes no sense to wrap the entire regex in a capturing group, as the entire match is just the default group 0.

---

If you just want to extract a full name like **"Alvaro de la Torre"** from a larger string, then just use `matcher.find()` instead of `matcher.matches()`, and get the  matched substring with `matcher.group()` (which gets the default group 0, that is, the match). In this case, also you don't need any explicit capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

First you'd like to know `\w` matches more than alphabets, like numbers `0-9`. So a string like `Jack is 23yrs old` is a complete match.

Second, there is a pipe in your grouping which if tries to bring a meaning of *optional* and is not there by accident, it's not a good way to demonstrate such quality. What's the right way? Using star `*` quantifier which includes *optional* feature essentially.

Third, `\s` means more than a [Space \x20](http://www.codetable.net/hex/20) character. It matches tabs `\t`, newlines `\n`, carriage returns `\r` too. So a string like

```
My name is
Jack
```

is a complete match as well.

Finally, you don't need capturing groups at all if you only need to return whole matched string:

```
(?i)[a-z]{2,}(?:[ ][a-z]{2,})*
```